# how do i switch between payment options with choosing currency for woocommerce store in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I want to add an option in checkout page to select the currency for payment ( USD or INR ) and based on that display the payment gateway option ( PAYPAL if USD or PAYUMONEY if INR and grey out the other option. I'm totally new to coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this:

```
function woocs_filter_gateways($gateway_list)
{
    global $WOOCS;
    $exclude = array(
        'paypal' => array('INR'), //do not show paypal gate if current currency is INR
        'payuindia' => array('USD')//do not show payumoney gate if current currency is USD
);
//***
foreach ($exclude as $gateway_key => $currencies)
{
    if (isset($gateway_list[$gateway_key]) AND in_array($WOOCS->current_currency, $currencies))
    {
        unset($gateway_list[$gateway_key]);
    }
}

return $gateway_list;
}
```